# How to speed up audit trigger?

Tags: mysql, trigger, audit

The task: write a trigger to log all updates within `tbl1` table for future audit users' actions.

The `tbl1` table:

```
id INT(11) 
y SMALLINT(6)
country SMALLINT(6)
-- really here ~20 fields but only some of them have to be monitored
```

I'm going to store both old & new values, one row for each field that was changed. The place for log (simplified for this example):

```
 CREATE TABLE z_log(
   id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   table_name CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   row_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   field CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   old_val VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   new_val VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
 )
```

The trigger I have created:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON tbl1
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- I'm interested in two fields only and if they were changed only
  IF new.y != old.y THEN
    SET @y = "('','tbl1',new.id,'y',old.y,new.y)";
  END IF;

  IF new.country != old.country THEN
    SET @country = "('','tbl1',new.id,'country',old.country,new.country)";
  END IF;

  if @y != '' or @country != '' THEN
    set @my_sql = concat('insert into z_lot values ', concat_ws(',', @y, @country), ';');
    prepare stmt1 from @my_sql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
  end if;

END
```

But I got error "dynamic sql is not allowed in stored function or trigger".
I can avoid 'execute'  by using a lot separated inserts: one for field 'y', one for field 'country' and ~10 inserts more for other fields but there will be performance penalty.

Is there any other fast way to log changes only?
Thank you.

Comment: Not really an answer, but [this post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/09/29/why-audit-logging-with-triggers-in-mysql-is-bad-for-replication/) outlines something to be aware of for replication: order of transaction completions.

Comment: @DTest thank you.I think there will be negligible difference in timestamps tor each transaction, it is enoygh for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could alter the trigger with brute force INSERTs as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 
    AFTER UPDATE 
    ON tbl1 
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE insert_style INT;

  -- I'm interested in two fields only and if they were changed only 

  SET insert_style = 0;
  IF new.y != old.y THEN 
      SET insert_style = 1;
  END IF;
  IF new.country != old.country THEN 
      SET insert_style = insert_style + 2;
  END IF; 

  CASE insert_style
      WHEN 1 THEN
          insert into z_lot values
          ('','tbl1',new.id,'y',old.y,new.y);
      WHEN 2 THEN
          insert into z_lot values
          ('','tbl1',new.id,'country',old.country,new.country);
      WHEN 3 THEN
          insert into z_lot values
          ('','tbl1',new.id,'y',old.y,new.y),
          ('','tbl1',new.id,'country',old.country,new.country);
  END CASE;      

END
```

Comment: Ugh, And for 10 fields we will have 2^10-1 cases... It looks crazy enough to test at least partialy :)

Answer (score -1):

I have spent a few days to come up with a Stored Procedure to automatically/dynamically create UPDATE / DELETE triggers in MariaDB (Works with v 10.1.9) auditing all changes on updates and deletions. The solution uses the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to automatically build an audit trigger for each of your tables. On Update only changed columns are audited, whilst on delete all the history is retained in the audit.

The Stored Procedure will give you a CREATE TRIGGER script which you can execute separately.

In the example below we create a test database with two tables, tb_company and tb_auditdetail which will hold our audit log.

```
    -- Dynamic Automated Update / Delete Triggers in MariaDB
    -- Leonard Tonna 19/05/2016 - www.ilabmalta.com

    CREATE DATABASE db_ilabmalta_test;

    USE db_ilabmalta_test;

    CREATE TABLE tb_auditDetail(
        audit_pk int(9) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        type varchar(1) NOT NULL,
        tablename varchar(128) NULL,
        pk varchar(128) NULL,
        fieldname varchar(128) NULL,
        oldvalue varchar(1000) NULL,
        newvalue varchar(1000) NULL,
        updatedate datetime NULL,
        username varchar(128) NULL,
        dbusername varchar(128) NULL,
        machinename varchar(128) NULL);

    CREATE TABLE tb_company(
        cmp_pk int(9) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        cmp_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        cmp_no varchar(16) NULL,
        cmp_status smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
        cmp_created datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        cmp_createdby varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        cmp_updated datetime NULL,
        cmp_updatedby varchar(10) NULL,
        cmp_record_version int(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ) ;

    -- We now create sp_maketrigger which is the stored procedure
    -- which will give us our trigger scripts

    DELIMITER $$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_maketrigger; 

    CREATE PROCEDURE sp_maketrigger (IN s_tablename CHAR(30), OUT u_trigger_out VARCHAR(65500) CHARACTER SET ascii,OUT d_trigger_out VARCHAR(65500) CHARACTER SET ascii)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE s_fieldname VARCHAR(50);
        DECLARE u_trigger VARCHAR(65500) CHARACTER SET ascii;
        DECLARE d_trigger VARCHAR(65500) CHARACTER SET ascii;
        DECLARE s_key VARCHAR(50);
        DECLARE s_updatedby VARCHAR(50);
        DECLARE s_updated VARCHAR(50);
        DECLARE s_recversion VARCHAR(50);
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0; 
        DECLARE cursor_end CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '02000'; 
        DECLARE col_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM test_prepare_vw;
        DECLARE pri_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM test_prepare_vw2;
        DECLARE upd_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM test_prepare_vw3;
        DECLARE rec_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM test_prepare_vw4;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR cursor_end SET done = 1; 

        DROP VIEW IF EXISTS test_prepare_vw; 
        DROP VIEW IF EXISTS test_prepare_vw2; 
        DROP VIEW IF EXISTS test_prepare_vw3; 
        DROP VIEW IF EXISTS test_prepare_vw4; 

        SET u_trigger = '';
        SET u_trigger = CONCAT('DELIMITER $$ \nDROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tra_',s_tablename,'_update;\n');
        SET u_trigger = CONCAT(u_trigger,'CREATE TRIGGER tra_',s_tablename,'_update AFTER UPDATE ON ',s_tablename,' FOR EACH ROW \n');
        SET u_trigger = CONCAT(u_trigger,'BEGIN \n');
        SET u_trigger = CONCAT(u_trigger,'DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255); \n');

        SET d_trigger = '';
        SET d_trigger = CONCAT('DELIMITER $$ \nDROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tra_',s_tablename,'_delete;\n');
        SET d_trigger = CONCAT(d_trigger,'CREATE TRIGGER tra_',s_tablename,'_delete AFTER DELETE ON ',s_tablename,' FOR EACH ROW \n');
        SET d_trigger = CONCAT(d_trigger,'BEGIN \n');

        SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW test_prepare_vw2 as SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = \'', s_tablename, '\' AND table_schema = \'db_diers\' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE \'%updated%\' AND COLUMN_KEY = \'PRI\' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION'); 
        PREPARE stmt from @query; 
        EXECUTE stmt; 
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 

        OPEN pri_cursor;
        FETCH pri_cursor INTO s_key; 
        CLOSE pri_cursor; 
        DROP VIEW test_prepare_vw2; 

        SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW test_prepare_vw3 as SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = \'', s_tablename, '\' AND table_schema = \'db_diers\' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE \'%updatedby%\' AND COLUMN_KEY <> \'PRI\' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION'); 
        PREPARE stmt from @query; 
        EXECUTE stmt; 
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 

        OPEN upd_cursor;
        FETCH upd_cursor INTO s_updatedby; 
        CLOSE upd_cursor; 
        DROP VIEW test_prepare_vw3; 
        SET s_updated = LEFT(s_updatedby,(LENGTH(RTRIM(s_updatedby)))-2);

        SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW test_prepare_vw4 as SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = \'', s_tablename, '\' AND table_schema = \'db_diers\' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE \'%record_version%\' AND COLUMN_KEY <> \'PRI\' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION'); 
        PREPARE stmt from @query; 
        EXECUTE stmt; 
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 

        OPEN rec_cursor;
        FETCH rec_cursor INTO s_recversion; 
        CLOSE rec_cursor; 
        DROP VIEW test_prepare_vw4; 

        SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW test_prepare_vw as SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = \'', s_tablename, '\' AND table_schema = \'db_diers\' AND COLUMN_KEY <> \'PRI\' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION'); 
        PREPARE stmt from @query; 
        EXECUTE stmt; 
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 

        SET u_trigger = CONCAT(u_trigger,'   IF (ISNULL(NEW.',s_recversion,') OR OLD.',s_recversion,' >= NEW.',s_recversion,' OR ISNULL(NEW.',s_updatedby,') OR NEW.',s_updatedby,' = \'\' OR ISNULL(NEW.',s_updated,') OR NEW.',s_updated,' = OLD.',s_updated,') THEN \n');
        SET u_trigger = CONCAT(u_trigger,'      set msg = \'Cannot update record without specifying updated/updatedby by columns and without incrementing the record version.\'; \n');
        SET u_trigger = CONCAT(u_trigger,'      SIGNAL SQLSTATE \'45000\' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg; \n');
        SET u_trigger = CONCAT(u_trigger,'   END IF;     \n');

        OPEN col_cursor;

        FETCH col_cursor INTO s_fieldname; 
        WHILE done = 0 DO 
            SET u_trigger = CONCAT(u_trigger,'   IF (IFNULL(OLD.',s_fieldname,',\'\') <> IFNULL(NEW.',s_fieldname,',\'\') ) THEN\n');
            SET u_trigger = CONCAT(u_trigger,'     INSERT INTO tb_auditdetail (type, tablename, pk, fieldname, oldvalue, newvalue, updatedate, username, dbusername, machinename) \n');
            SET u_trigger = CONCAT(u_trigger,'     VALUES (\'U\', \'',s_tablename,'\', OLD.',s_key,', \'',s_fieldname,'\', OLD.',s_fieldname,', NEW.',s_fieldname,', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,NEW.',s_updatedby,',CURRENT_USER(),@@hostname);\n');
            SET u_trigger = CONCAT(u_trigger,'   END IF;\n'); 

            SET d_trigger = CONCAT(d_trigger,'     INSERT INTO tb_auditdetail (type, tablename, pk, fieldname, oldvalue, newvalue, updatedate, username, dbusername, machinename) \n');
            SET d_trigger = CONCAT(d_trigger,'     VALUES (\'D\', \'',s_tablename,'\', OLD.',s_key,', \'',s_fieldname,'\', OLD.',s_fieldname,',NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,NULL,CURRENT_USER(),@@hostname);\n');

            FETCH col_cursor INTO s_fieldname; 
        END WHILE; 
        CLOSE col_cursor; 

        DROP VIEW test_prepare_vw; 

        SET u_trigger = CONCAT(u_trigger,'END;$$ \nDELIMITER ; \n');
        SET d_trigger = CONCAT(d_trigger,'END;$$ \nDELIMITER ; \n');
        SELECT u_trigger INTO u_trigger_out;
        SELECT d_trigger INTO d_trigger_out;


    END; $$

    DELIMITER ;

    -- And finally, to extract the Trigger Scripts

    call sp_maketrigger('tb_company',@s_line1,@d_line1);

    SELECT CONCAT(@s_line1,@d_line1)

    -- You just need to copy, paste and execute the trigger script, and
    -- voila, your audit is in place.
```

The above example takes it for granted that with each of your tables you have 5 columns: created, createdby, updated, updatedby, record_version.

However you can customise the Stored Procedure sp_maketrigger differently to suit your needs. The sp is also subject to enhancements and improvements.

Leonard Tonna

iLabMalta

www.ilabmalta.com

Comment: This procedure may be useful in general but how is your suggestion relevant to this specific question?